# In springboot css and js files not loading in jsp file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In spring-boot application, pointed all *css*, *js*, *images* are in below structure:

[image]

JSP page is loading with all *css/js/images* when the URL is like this http://localhost:8080/request/

But when the URL is like this http://localhost:8080/request/rt/home
(*css/image/js* are not loading).

When I click the url of `bootstrap.min.css` from view source page, it is showing like below: 
http://localhost:8080/request/rt/public/css/bootstrap.min.css

"rt" is adding in between the url.
How to omit the "rt" from path.
so that will get path like http://localhost:8080/request/public/css/bootstrap.min.css

It will load *css/js/images*
Please suggest

Comment: Are you creating JAR or WAR archive?

Comment: just started development..from eclipse application is running..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your `jsp`, according to your statements of how it behaves, I would say that you are declaring your stylesheet and resources reference this way, without starting by a `/`:

```
<link href="public/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="public/css/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This means that the resources are relative to the virtual directory of the url bar of the browser.

You should declare your references this way:

```
<link href="/request/public/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="/request/public/css/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

To avoid hardcoding the contextpath, you could use:

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/public/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/public/css/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Whicho would resolve your context name

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<link href="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

or

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```